# How to allow PHP to find functions

Tags: php

I am new to PHP. I have a function that is in a folder. PHP can't seem to find this function. What can I do to allow PHP to find/see the file that contains the function I am trying to use?

EDIT:

Here is the code I am using

```
<?php

include './blog/wp-includes/post.php';

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts();
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent )
{
echo '<li><a href="' 
        . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) 
        . '" title="Look '
        .esc_attr($recent["post_title"])
        .'" >' 
        .   $recent["post_title"]
        .'</a> </li> ';
    }
```

but when I execute the code, I get:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in /home/hilan1/public_html/site/blog/wp-includes/post.php on line 144
```

Comment: *PHP can't seem to find this function* Why? What are you doing? What happens? What is the exact error message? You have to include the corresponding files if you want to use functions from them (similar like in other languages. Java, C (I guess C++, C#), Python,...).

Comment: add the path of folder to that file where the function is writtern

Answer (score 0):

- [`include()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)
- [`include_once()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)
- [`require()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)
- [`require_once()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

Also look into autoloading if you're using classes:

- [`__autoload()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php)
- [`spl_autoload()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php)

**edit**

You will need to include the file that contains the WordPress function `add_action()` before using another function that uses it.

Comment: Can you do this for an entire directory? It looks like you can only do it for a file.

Comment: No, you would have to include each file separately. You may want to cehck out autoloading which I will add to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Ive included what I am trying to do in my answer. Don't know if it will help at all

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Thats what I thought might be happening.

Answer (score 0):

I will make you an example:

Suppose you have the following structure in your root:

- index.php
- important (folder) / functions.php (inside folder)

Example of the "functions.php" file:

```
<?php

  function HelloWorld($name){
    return "Hello ".$name;
  }  

?>
```

In your index.php file do the following:

```
<?php
include('important/functions.php');

$name = "Oscar";
$result = HelloWorld($name);
echo $result;

?>
```

That's a simple way to invoke functions in other files.

Hope this helps.